# Filter a reactive object, based on other reactive object, while both depend on a third reactive object

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I´m trying to filter a reactive object "#4" using other reactive object "#3" with no success, and I think the problem is that they both depend on another reactive "#2". This picture should help:

[image: problem]

Here is the `reprex`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

dat <- as.data.frame( list(
  X = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
  Y = c(1,2,3,4,5)
))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("myinput", "Input:",min = 1, max = 5,value = 3)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      fluidRow(column(2, DTOutput('table_data'))),
      br(),
      fluidRow(column(2, DTOutput('table_filtered'))),
      br(),
      fluidRow(column(2, DTOutput('table_filtered_not_A'))),
      br(),br(),
      fluidRow(column(2, DTOutput('table_grouped')))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dat_rv <- reactiveValues(df = dat)
  
  dat_filtered <- reactive({
    dat_rv$df %>% 
      filter(
        !isTruthy( input$myinput ) | Y <= input$myinput
      )
  })
  
  dat_not_A <- reactive({
    dat_not_A <- dat_filtered() %>%
      filter(X != "A") %>% 
      select(X)
  })
  
  dat_grouped <- reactive({
    dat_grouped <- dat_filtered() %>%
      filter(X %in% dat_not_A()) %>% # HERE IS THE PROBLEM?
      group_by(X) %>%
      summarise(Y = sum(Y))
    return(dat_grouped)
  })
  
  output$table_data = renderDT(dat, options = list(dom = 't'), rownames = FALSE)
  output$table_filtered = renderDT(dat_filtered(), options = list(dom = 't'), rownames = FALSE)
  output$table_filtered_not_A = renderDT(dat_not_A(), options = list(dom = 't'), rownames = FALSE)
  output$table_grouped = renderDT(dat_grouped(), options = list(dom = 't'), rownames = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have also tried to use isolate but it has not work. Am i missing something?

Best regards.

Comment: Shouldn't you be filtering from `X` ? `filter(X %in% unique(dat_not_A()$X)) ....`

Comment: good catch! now it works... I need to look at the real example, beacuse there it doesn´t

Comment: I´m going to edit the question and add an answer so that all this makes sense. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
  dat_grouped <- reactive({
    dat_grouped <- dat_filtered() %>%
      filter(X %in% unique(dat_not_A()$X)) %>% 
      group_by(X) %>%
      summarise(Y = sum(Y))
    return(dat_grouped)
  })
```

And not:

```
  dat_grouped <- reactive({
    dat_grouped <- dat_filtered() %>%
      filter(X %in% dat_not_A()) %>%
      group_by(X) %>%
      summarise(Y = sum(Y))
    return(dat_grouped)
  })
```